# Why can I not enter large values (e.x. n = 100000) in this program that calculates all prime numbers from 0 to n inclusive?

Tags: java, for-loop, primes

I'm fairly new to coding, I just started learning Java this semester. I was messing around and created this java program that finds all prime numbers from 0 to n inclusive. It uses modulus and a nested for loop and outputs it in an arraylist. Now, I tested it with n = 5, n= 100, n = 1000 and n= 10000 and it worked completely fine and gave me accurate results, however when I inputted n = 100000, the console simply was blank and didnt give me any output at all. I realize that with large numbers it will take longer, so I was expecting to wait for it to number-crunch it all, but it just "gave up".

Is this the result of some calculation time-out? Is there a overide so I can calculate this with larger numbers? I realize this is not the most efficient code (i.e. there are calculations in the for loops that may be done twice) but thats not what the issue is here. The issue is why does a certain number stop output and is there any way to bypass this.

I put my code below, separated into two blocks because I have it in two different classes.

Thanks :)

General.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class General 
{
    
    
    

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        System.out.print("What is the number you want to find all the primes that are smaller than it: ");
        long n = number.nextInt();
        
        PrimeNumberSeeker pNS = new PrimeNumberSeeker();
        
        result = pNS.PrimesFromZero(n);
        
        for (int m = 0; m < result.size(); m++)
                {
                System.out.print(result.get(m));
                
                if (m+1 >= (result.size()))
                    System.out.print(".");
                else 
                    System.out.print(", ");
                }

    }

}
```

PrimeNumberSeeker.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class PrimeNumberSeeker 
{
    ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    
    public ArrayList<Integer> PrimesFromZero(long n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) //selects all numbers from 0 - n inclusive
        {
            int check = 0;
            //System.out.println(i);
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) //we make sure not to include 1 and itself (n)
            {
                
                
                    if (i % j == 0)
                    check += 1;
                
                
                
                //System.out.println(i + " " + j);
            }
            if (check == 2)
                primes.add(i);
                
        }
        
        return primes;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: it just "gave up" ... why do you think that? did you get an error message? what does it say?

Comment: It is just a problem of computational complexity, your algorithm could be optimized under different aspects in order to lower its complexity

Comment: https://www.interviewcake.com/concept/java/memoization - *Memoization ensures that a method doesn't run for the same inputs more than once by keeping a record of the results for the given inputs (usually in a hash map).*

Comment: @aran you might want to add some information with that link.

Comment: @Stultuske is it better now? Its method doesn't say anything, because its time complexity grows exponentially. *Memoization consist in caching the results of functions in order to speed them up when they are called several times*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a problem of computational complexity, your algorithm could be optimized under different aspects to lower its complexity:

- you don't need the `check` variable
- you can limit the `j` range from 2 to sqrt(i)
- if `i%j==0` you can stop your investigation on `i`: it is not prime

Other advice:

- always use parenthesis
- use lowerCamelCase for functions' names
- don't mix `int`s and `long`s, for your purposes `int`s are enough

This algorithm is not the best but works well with numbers up to 10.000.000 (or something more):

```
class PrimeNumberSeeker {
    public ArrayList<Integer> primesFromZero(int n) {
        ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            boolean isPrime = true; // say your number is prime (we'll verify)
            for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) { // verify if it really is
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    isPrime = false; // it isn't
                    break; // no more checks are needed, go out from this for cycle
                }
            }
            
            if (isPrime) { // if isPrime is still true then i is prime
                primes.add(i);
            }
        }
        
        return primes;
    }
}
```

Comment: ohhh this makes alot of sense actually, thank you for the detailed answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your program is running. I just tested it. You can visualize the progress by printing every found prime imediatly:

```
        if (check == 2) {
            primes.add(i);
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

What you can also see, is that the progress becomes slower the bigger the numbers get. That is because your [rumtime complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) is O(n^2) (squared). For each number you test each number that is lower. That means if you go from n=10.000 to n=100.000 your programm needs far more than 10 times the time.

For prime calculation check out the algorithm [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). This is far more efficient in terms of calculation time.